# Link Errors in Unmodified Visual Studio 2012 MFC Template when Statically Linking MFC

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, visual-studio-2012, linker-errors

When creating a new MFC application of the simplest kind in Visual Studio 2012, and setting it to link statically to MFC, linking fails.

**Here's a [gallery of 7 screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGTSg.jpg)** starting from the creation of the project via the wizard, up to the building (resulting in the linker error). 
**No source editing was done in-between.**

The error logs state:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Test, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  stdafx.cpp
1>  TestDlg.cpp
1>  Test.cpp
1>  Generating Code...
1>uafxcwd.lib(afxctrlcontainer2.obj) : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl AfxRegisterMFCCtrlClasses(void)" (?AfxRegisterMFCCtrlClasses@@YAXXZ) already defined in afxnmcdd.lib(afxctrlcontainer2.obj)
1>uafxcwd.lib(afxctrlcontainer2.obj) : error LNK2005: "protected: void __thiscall CMFCControlContainer::PreUnsubclassControl(class CWnd *)" (?PreUnsubclassControl@CMFCControlContainer@@IAEXPAVCWnd@@@Z) already defined in afxnmcdd.lib(afxctrlcontainer2.obj)
1>uafxcwd.lib(afxctrlcontainer2.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: int __thiscall CMFCControlContainer::SubclassDlgControls(void)" (?SubclassDlgControls@CMFCControlContainer@@QAEHXZ) already defined in afxnmcdd.lib(afxctrlcontainer2.obj)
1>C:\Users\XXXXXXXX\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Test\Debug\Test.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Is this just me? Would you have a suggestion on how to address this?

Comment: If I had to hazard a guess I'd say the wizard is broken. If you're linking to the static MFC and CRT the [auto-magic setup from afx.h](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bx5yfk7t.aspx) should take care of this for you. Assuming you're compiling with Unicode support (it appears you are, anyway; who doesn't these days?) the proper lib appears to be `uafxcwd.lib` for static-unicode-debug. Either the second lib shouldn't be there at all, or the linker order is wrong. I'd be curious to know what happens if you turn *off* Unicode suppport and rebuild-all after blowing away your PCH files.

Comment: I think you should report this to Microsoft as a bug.  I think you can do that right from the Help menu in VS 2012. Then remove all the libraries that seem bogus like `afxnmcdd.lib` from your linker options, and just add back `uafxcwd.lib`. Maybe add `/NODEFAULTLIBS`

Comment: @warren-p I agree. I definitely will be doing so, to save others the headache of tracing this issue. Hopefully (?) it's an actual bug and not something specific to my set-up.

Comment: See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/02/06/10263387.aspx for some background about why these symbols reside in both `uafxcw.lib` and `afxnmcd.lib`. Since it's intentional that the libraries have duplicate symbols, I think you might need to use `/force:multiple` to build with this set of options.  `/force:multiple` does enable the project to build and run, but I'm really not familiar enough with MFC to know if that's a correct workaround/fix or if it just hides a problem.

Answer (score 5):

I got the same problem when I try static link my project together.

As Michael Burr suggested, it seems fine after commented out the line of #define _AFX_NO_MFC_CONTROLS_IN_DIALOGS in stdafx.h.

Answer (score 2):

I've come across the same issue. If you decide to `#define _AFX_NO_MFC_CONTROLS_IN_DIALOGS` and get rid of a lot MFC overhead you should also be sure you change the dialog base classes, method calls,etc from `CDialogEx` to `CDialog`.

If you don't change the background color or the image of your dialog, you will find that `CDialogEx` is pretty useless anyway.

Answer (score 0):

After tested, v100 works well and v110 does not work. Try to report to MS connect as this link:  http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/581084/linker-cant-locate-some-external-symbol-when-use-mfc-in-a-static-library