# Duplicate symbols when static linking MFC

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, mfc

I have a solution that's been building fine for months. Yesterday I did a full rebuild following a clean that was performed to reduce the solution size for backup, but one of the sub projects failed to link.

A bit of background:

This sub-project is a DLL that always linked statically to MFC, but was recently changed to dynamic linkage because it was assumed the reason for it having been static was no longer an issue (it was previously used by an MFC app built under VC++ 6, and this is a VS 2013 MFC DLL, but the main app has since been migrated to this same VS 2013 solution, so they should both be happy linking dynamically to the same version of MFC, shouldn't they?). As it turns out, the DLL links but crashes on the call to DoModal() when built dynamically (anwswers to this separate question on a postcard, if you'd be so kind). So I switched it back to static.

Back to the question proper:

On rebuilding with static linkage I got the following errors:

```
1>uafxcwd.lib(afxctrlcontainer2.obj) : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl AfxRegisterMFCCtrlClasses(void)" (?AfxRegisterMFCCtrlClasses@@YAXXZ) already defined in afxnmcdd.lib(afxctrlcontainer2.obj)
1>uafxcwd.lib(afxctrlcontainer2.obj) : error LNK2005: "protected: void __thiscall CMFCControlContainer::PreUnsubclassControl(class CWnd *)" (?PreUnsubclassControl@CMFCControlContainer@@IAEXPAVCWnd@@@Z) already defined in afxnmcdd.lib(afxctrlcontainer2.obj)
1>uafxcwd.lib(afxctrlcontainer2.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: int __thiscall CMFCControlContainer::SubclassDlgControls(void)" (?SubclassDlgControls@CMFCControlContainer@@QAEHXZ) already defined in afxnmcdd.lib(afxctrlcontainer2.obj)
```

Searching for this issue on line I understand it's fixable by simply commenting out

```
#define _AFX_NO_MFC_CONTROLS_IN_DIALOGS
```

in the cuplprit project's stdafx.h. But what's really bugging me is why this is necessary only now, after linking it statically so many times without issue? The project hasn't just been sat there not needing a rebuild by the way, it's been changed and rebuilt plenty of times. So has some VS wizard inserted that line at some point when toggling between static/dynamic? And why have some define in the first place if you can't link statically when using it?

So I have everything working as it was now, I'm just curious how this came about ...

Edit:

I forgot to mention that the first answer to this question also has me a bit worried, because I now have that #define removed but do still have a CDialogEx derived class:
[Link Errors in Unmodified Visual Studio 2012 MFC Template when Statically Linking MFC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13589518/link-errors-in-unmodified-visual-studio-2012-mfc-template-when-statically-linkin)

Comment: As I recall, DLLs that used MFC had to be one of three kinds, to conform to some silly super-complex scheme for accessing resources. Probably won't help you but I would try to create some such DLLs from scratch. Better control then.

Comment: Your initial approach to use dynamic linking of MFC with the DLL is more appropriate.  Rather than falling back to a static library approach, you should try to debug why the DoModal call fails.  Have you stepped into the code in debug?  More than likely, it's not finding your dialog resource and DoModal is returning a -1.  Either way, the more appropriate approach is to not ignore the DoModal failure.

Comment: @rrirower. I looked into the DoModal() failure and have now added AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState()); ahead of the call. I'm quite surprised this is necessary and that I haven't come across it before. I'd still be interested to know why it suddenly stopped linking statically, but in all honestly getting it working dynamically does kind of make that academic now.

Comment: MFC manages state per module. When linking everything statically into one module you will not experience resource lookup issues. When compiling resources into DLLs, MFC needs to know which module contains a particular resource. The `AFX_MANAGE_STATE` macro sets the state to the current module, and it should be used in every DLL export.